# SQL Database for related family members

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, aliases

I am curious what you think is the best way to get this MySQL database to work.

i had this table:

```
family.id
family.name
family.related
```

And thought it wouldnt be a problem to connect related family members together in 1 query like this:

```
id        | name        | related
1         | Name1       | 
2         | Name2       | 3,5
3         | Name3       | 
4         | Name4       | 
5         | Name5       | 4,1
6         | Name6       | 
7         | Name7       | 
8         | Name8       | 6
9         | Name9       | 7
```

So Name2 is related to Name3 and Name5, where Name5 have other related id's, so i should make a query to get the following id's:

Selecting id 2, outputs related id's: 3,5,**4,1**

Selecting id 6, outputs related id's: 8

Selecting id 9, outputs related id's: 7

But i cant find a query to get all the related id's in one column.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Oracle has hierarchical query functions to do that.  I wonder if there is a similar construct for mysql?

Comment: You want to represent a hierarchy in SQL table. There is a good answer, describing, how to it efficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree

Comment: I am sorry, but i cannot make sense out of the answer, can you please help explaining how to use it for the databse structure above?

Answer (score 0):

For a many-to-many relationship, you'll generally need to use a linking table:

```
family_id
related_to
```

Where, when you would have several comma-delimited items in your family table, you would instead have one entry in the linking table for each item that would be in the comma-delimited list:

```
family_id | related_to
2           3
2           5
5           4
5           1
...
```

And so on.

Comment: but when i select family_id 5, how do i get family_id 2 outputted as well? How will the query look like, can i do it in the same query when looking up information in the family table? with a JOIN for example?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me out with this problem?

Comment: You can `SELECT * WHERE family_id = X OR related_to = X`.